# Recommended architecture of Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have coded an Azure Function App that transfers product data between two APIs. The app takes about 20-30 minutes to run (on this particular client's data set).

When I looked at the Live Metrics Monitoring in Azure, I realized that the Function App was running two server instances. I looked at the Function App's `App Service Plan` and saw that the `Maximum Burst` was set to 20 (which is probably default).

[image: Scale out App Service Plan set to Burst 20]

If I understand this correctly, 20 means that Azure will spin up up to 20 instances of the app (different VMs) to accomodate the load under stress.

My code is written the way that it's supposed to handle all the data that is being transferred between the two APIs each time it runs. If I had spun up two instances on my local machine, the two instances would go about doing the same job in parallel, which is a waste.

1. Did I understand out-scaling correctly?
2. Should I reprogram the app so it only processes one product at a time?
3. Or should I just set Burst to 1?

Comment: first question: how do you trigger your Function? HTTP? Queue? etc?

Comment: Timer, every hour or so

Comment: then I'd suggest - if thats possible: The timer-triggered Function should only kick off a Durable Function orchestrator. This starts one Activity Function for each unit of work

Comment: Consider using a queue in between, so 1 function would process the data onto queue, the other function then reads the messages from queue, this would give you reliability and also independently scale each function.  If message size a problem, could save data into storage and use queue to reference part of that storage.

Comment: Ah, okay. So what you are saying is that: Yes, this is the way multiple instances is supposed to work, and: Yes, try to make the code process as little as possible each time it runs - and finally: You can use Azure Queues to store the "work to be done" into and then pick one each time the app runs. Right?

Comment: yes - you can break the work into batches and then function can scale to process multiple batches at once, this can be done via durable functions as comment above or through queues as per my comment, if not each instance of the function will do the same thing